BigQuery Data transfer crashes with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Creating table with tags is not supported
I have crashlytics being synchronized in BigQuery and I have a Data transfer job configured to copy its data from US to EU region. It was working great for years and now I got an error, since 1 week.
That Data transfer is a simple "Dataset Copy", from source "firebase_crashlytics" (in US), to destination "firebase_crashlytics_eu". I guess this is the usual way to synchronize Crashlytics data to BigQuery EU. Nothing fantastic here ;)
Yet, my jobs fail with this error:
BigQuery job bqts_66b11d31-0000-2c97-be17-582429cc3f48 (table com_XXXX_IOS_REALTIME) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Creating table with tags is not supported.; JobID: XXXXX:bqts_66b11d31-0000-2c97-be17-582429cc3f48. Check BigQuery job details for more information.

When I check that BigQuery job details, nothing special there.
I have no clue what this "table with tags" means. My source tables or dataset have no tag, my columns have no "policy tag". This error Creating table with tags is not supported makes no sense to me.
Any idea?

Hi @gjanvier, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

@gjanvier, FYI we've encountered the same issue (the commonality is that we're copying a US (multiregion) dataset to an EU (single region) dataset every day. It's worked fine for ages and is now failing with this error. Did you open an issue that I can upvote, rather than create my own?

I have located a relevant issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/353997479
N.B. if your organisation is affected you can upvote it, but it looks like GCP have prioritised it.

I spoke with GCP Support about this bug, which is affecting many people.
A root cause fix is underway, but it seems clear that

the data transfer service doesn't support cross-region copy for tables with tags
for some reason, the system mistakenly believes that certain tables have tags, even though they do not (and the UI says they do not)

Since (2) is the case, GCP Support told me you can fix your problem by removing the (nonexistent) tags. It's simple:

make sure you have the latest version of the gcloud CLI installed
run the command bq update --clear_all_tags <TABLE_NAME> from the command line

This unblocked things for us.
